# ABCPDF Reading PDF as background image, next page doesnt render

Tags: abcpdf

We have 4 Html pages that we are joining together into 1 file.
For the first page, we are reading a blank PDF file (letter head) to add as the background and then add the further 3 pages.
However, all seemed ok in version 8, but now the second page will not show.

thedoc reads the blank pdf and then the html page which overlays the text no issue here.
thedoc1 is the second page which will not load
thedoc1a and thedoc2 load ok.
If I remove the adding of the letter head from thedoc, then all 4 pages load ok, but as soon as I try and use the letter head, the second page doesnt load.

Ive added my script below. What I am doing wrong please

```
Sub page_load()
    Dim rs
    Dim strSQLQuery As String
    Dim theDoc As Doc = New Doc()
    Dim theDoc1 As Doc = New Doc()
    Dim theDoc1a As Doc = New Doc()
    Dim theDoc2 As Doc = New Doc()  

    Dim theDoccontents As Doc = New Doc()
    theDoc.MediaBox.String = "A4"
    theDoc1.MediaBox.String = "A4"
    theDoc1a.MediaBox.String = "A4"
    theDoc2.MediaBox.String = "A4
   
    theDoc.HtmlOptions.PageCacheEnabled = False
    theDoc.HtmlOptions.PageCacheClear()

    theDoc.HtmlOptions.ImageQuality = 33
    theDoc1.HtmlOptions.ImageQuality = 33
    theDoc1a.HtmlOptions.ImageQuality = 33
    theDoc2.HtmlOptions.ImageQuality = 33
   
    theDoc.HtmlOptions.AddLinks = True
    theDoc1.HtmlOptions.AddLinks = True
    theDoc1a.HtmlOptions.AddLinks = True
    theDoc2.HtmlOptions.AddLinks = True
   
    theDoc.HtmlOptions.Timeout = 10000000
    theDoc1.HtmlOptions.Timeout = 10000000
    theDoc1a.HtmlOptions.Timeout = 10000000
    theDoc2.HtmlOptions.Timeout = 10000000
   
   
    Dim rbrandchosen As String
    Dim quotenumber As String
    Dim rnum As String
    Dim cover as string
    dim pagex as integer
    quotenumber=request("quotenumber")
    rbrandchosen=request("rbrandchosen")
    response.write(quotenumber)
    Dim theURL As String
    Dim theID As Integer
    Dim strsql as string
    Dim theSection as string
    Dim theCountDoc1a As Integer

    Randomize()
    rnum = (CInt(Math.Floor(90 * Rnd())) + 10).ToString
     

        ' add covering letter
       
        cover = "c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\icopalukintranet\\pnf\\letterhead.pdf"
   
            theDoc.Read(cover)

            'theID = theDoc.AddObject("<< >>")



           
            theDoc.HtmlOptions.UseScript = True
            theDoc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Chrome86
            ' Render after 2 seconds

            theDoc.Rect.SetRect(20, 110, 600, 620)
            theDoc.HtmlOptions.OnLoadScript = "(function(){ window.ABCpdf_go = false;     setTimeout(function(){ window.ABCpdf_go = true; }, 3000); })();"

            theURL = "http://localhost/icopalukintranet/pnf/rooflights/rooflightquotepdfletter.asp?quotenumber="+ quotenumber + "&stridrnd="+rnum
            'theDoc.AddImageUrl(theURL)
            theID = theDoc.AddImageUrl(theURL)
            While True
               
                If Not theDoc.Chainable(theID) Then
                    Exit While
                End If
                theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage()
                theID = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theID)
            End While


            ' add quote

           

         
            theDoc1.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Chrome86
            theDoc1.HtmlOptions.UseScript = True
            theDoc1.Rect.SetRect(0, 0, 600, 820)
            ' Render after 2 seconds
            theDoc1.HtmlOptions.OnLoadScript = "(function(){ window.ABCpdf_go = false; setTimeout(function(){ window.ABCpdf_go = true; }, 2000); })();"

       
        theURL = "http://localhost/icopalukintranet/pnf/rooflights/rooflightquotepdfquote.asp?quotenumber="+ quotenumber + "&stridrnd="+rnum
 

            theDoc1.Page = theDoc1.AddPage()
           

            theID = theDoc1.AddImageUrl(theURL)

            While True
               
                If Not theDoc1.Chainable(theID) Then
                    Exit While
                End If
                theSection = "Quote"
                theDoc1.Page = theDoc1.AddPage()
                theID = theDoc1.AddImageToChain(theID)
                theDoc1.AddBookmark(theSection, True)
            End While

     


        ' add notes

      
        theDoc1a.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Chrome86
        theDoc1a.HtmlOptions.UseScript = True
        theDoc1a.Rect.SetRect(0, 0, 600, 820)
        ' Render after 3 seconds
        theDoc1a.HtmlOptions.OnLoadScript = "(function(){ window.ABCpdf_go = false; setTimeout(function(){ window.ABCpdf_go = true; }, 1000); })();"

       
        theURL = "http://localhost/icopalukintranet/pnf/rooflights/rooflightquotepdfnotes.asp?quotenumber="+ quotenumber + "&stridrnd="+rnum
   

       theDoc1a.Page = theDoc1a.AddPage()
       

        theID = theDoc1a.AddImageUrl(theURL)
        While True
           
            If Not theDoc1a.Chainable(theID) Then
                Exit While
            End If
            theDoc1a.Page = theDoc1a.AddPage()
            theID = theDoc1a.AddImageToChain(theID)
        End While

     


        ' add terms details



        theDoc2.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Chrome86
        theDoc2.HtmlOptions.UseScript = True
       theDoc2.Rect.SetRect(20, 80, 560, 710)
    theDoc2.Transform.Magnify(0.93 ,0.93, 0, 690)
        ' Render after 1 seconds
        theDoc2.HtmlOptions.OnLoadScript = "(function(){ window.ABCpdf_go = false; setTimeout(function(){ window.ABCpdf_go = true; }, 2000); })();"
       
        theURL = "http://localhost/icopalukintranet/pnf/rooflights/rooflightquotepdfterms.asp?quotenumber="+ quotenumber + "&stridrnd="+rnum
   

         theDoc2.Page = theDoc2.AddPage()
       

        theID = theDoc2.AddImageUrl(theURL)
        While True

            If Not theDoc2.Chainable(theID) Then
                Exit While
            End If
            theSection = "Terms"
            theDoc2.Page = theDoc2.AddPage()
            theID = theDoc2.AddImageToChain(theID)
            theDoc2.AddBookmark(theSection, True)
        End While






       



    Dim cst = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("rooflightquotes.mdb")
    Dim conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.open(cst)
    Session("myConn") = conn

    dim rsAddquestion = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    strsql ="select * from pdfs where id=" & quotenumber & " "
    rsAddquestion.Open(strsql, conn, 3, 3)

    dim n as string
    n=rsAddquestion.recordcount
    rsAddquestion.AddNew
    n=n+1
    rsAddquestion("id")=quotenumber
    rsAddquestion("pdfname") =quotenumber +"-rev"+n+".pdf"
    rsAddquestion("printdate")=now()
    rsAddquestion("status")="Printed"

    rsAddquestion.update

    rsAddquestion = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    strsql ="select * from header where id=" & quotenumber & " "
    rsAddquestion.Open(strsql, conn, 3, 3)
    rsAddquestion("status")="Printed"
    rsAddquestion.update


    conn.close

   




       
       


       

        ' add the pdf together in selected order

       
        theDoc.Append(theDoc1)  
        theDoc.Append(theDoc1a)  
        theDoc.Append(theDoc2)
       

       

        Dim theCount = theDoc.PageCount
        '    left bottom width heght
        theDoc.Rect.String = "10 10 580 25"
        theDoc.HPos = 1.0
        theDoc.VPos = 0.5
        theDoc.Color.String = "255 255 255"

        theDoc.Font = theDoc.AddFont("Arial")
        theDoc.FontSize = 10
        For i = 1 To theCount
            theDoc.PageNumber = i
            If i <> 1 Then
       theDoc.AddHtml(" Page " + i.ToString() + " of " + theCount.ToString() + "")
                theDoc.FrameRect()
            End If
        Next


        dim pdffilenamec  = "pdf/"+quotenumber+"-rev"+n+".pdf"
      theDoc.Save(Server.MapPath(pdffilenamec))

       


       'response.redirect("rooflightquotepdfmenu.asp?quotenumber="+quotenumber)
 


End Sub
```

This used to work find in version 8, but  not now using version 12